# Visual Studio Code: Ajustar linea de código a ventana

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

El editor en VSC pone las lineas de codigo fuera de la ventana (no le aplica salto cuando el texto es mas largo).

Se ve asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que cuando el codigo llegue al limite de la ventana aplique el salto pero no encuentro cual es el comando o donde esta la configuracion para poder editar eso. De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

solo escribe

**alt + z**

esto activa y desactiva el **word wrap**

puedes encontrar la lista completa de comandos en el siguiente enlace https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: Perfecto, es todo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.